# windows phone 8 new emotion icons

Tags: twitter, windows-phone-8, emoji

I am working on twitter client for Windows phone 8. In Windows phone 8, Microsoft had added new emoji icons and can able to tweet from tweet window.

My issue is, whenever i tweeted emoji icons twitter statuses(list of tweets) shows square boxes only.

Please help me in resolving this, so that proper emoji icons can be viewed in Timeline.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Uri.EscapeDataString to encode the status text.